# Thread stops executing

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have a Thread that is running a shell script in an external process, and I'm using Apache's IOUtils to read in the stderr and stdout streams from this external process as follows:

```
Thread t = new Thread(()-> {
        ProcessBuilder pb =  new ProcessBuilder("sh");
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = pb.start();
            OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
            os.write("sleep 30 ; echo test".getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            InputStream es = p.getErrorStream();
            String stdout = IOUtils.toString(is,"UTF-8");
            String stderr = IOUtils.toString(es,"UTF-8");
            int retval = p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Got exception: "+e.toString());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Done now!");
        }
    });
t.start();
Thread.sleep(7000);
t.interrupt();
```

For some reason, when I run this test case, the exception is never thrown (the `catch` block never runs), and the `finally` block never runs. Is there some problem that I'm not catching? Should stdout and stderr be collected by a different thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the buffer for stderr fills up your program will stop. Unless you need them to be in different Strings I would redirect one to the other.

I would use [ProcessBuidler.redirectErrorStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-) to combine the outputs so you don't need an additional thread to read the stderr

[waitFor(long, TimeUnit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) has a timeout so you don't need to start a background thread.

I suggest you printout your stderr and stdout so you can see them as they might give an indication of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct, apart from the fact that the thread is killed (interrupted) before it could process any output from the shell. The issue is that the shell sleeps for 30 seconds and the thread is interrupted in 7 seconds.

The fact you don't see any message from catch or finally block could be caused by exiting the program from the `main()` method before the "shell" thread is actually activated.